# File dvips.ref not found; while dvips package is installed

Tags: moderncv, dvips

I am trying to compile an example from `moderncv` package, but get the following error:

```
velle@velle-s200e:~/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/examples$ latex template.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./template.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
(/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter d
ocument class
(/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)

! LaTeX Error: File `dvips.def' not found.
```

## Package dvips already installed:

I did the "minimal (plain only)" installation of texlive. And it seems to come with dvips. Dvips is located as shown below:

```
velle@velle-s200e:~$ tlmgr install dvips
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr install: package already present: dvips
```

## dvips-files present

```
velle@velle-s200e:~$ find ~/texlive/ -name "*dvips*"
/home/velle/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-local/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/dvips/dvips.html
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/dvips/dvips.pdf
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/info/dvips.info
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/dvips.1
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/dvips.man1.pdf
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/tetex/dvips35.map
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/dvips.enc
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/odvips.enc
/home/velle/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips
/home/velle/texlive/tlpkg/tlpobj/dvips.x86_64-linux.tlpobj
/home/velle/texlive/tlpkg/tlpobj/dvips.tlpob
```

So why can it not find dvips? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the `graphics` package installed? As far as I know, `dvips.def` is part of it.

Comment: I came across the file a couple of days ago and remembered the package name. Just verified it with `kpsewhich dvips.def`. If it's not installed, you have to search CTAN for the file name, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The file `dvips.def` is is part of the `graphics` package.

If you have a system available on which your example compiles successfully, you can locate the file with `kpsewhich dvips.def`, for example. Otherwise, try to use the search facility at CTAN that also allows to search for file names, or grep `ftp://ftp.ctan.org/pub/tex/FILES.byname.gz`. However, this way you can't lookup files inside archives (like `dvips.def` which is provided by `/install/macros/latex/required/graphics.tds.zip`).